# how to sorting value in treeview

Tags: python, treeview

I'm trying to sort the value by finish time but still failed. See the image below![https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N0uAnOyHHsfw2Q_SIiEDnZ7fPc6v_IcQ/view?usp=sharing]

I expected the finish time column to be sorted in ascending order.

```
def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
    l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
    l.sort(key=lambda t: int(t[0]), reverse=reverse)
    #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
        tv.move(k, '', index)

    tv.heading(col,
               command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))
def showresult():
    global result_screen
    ga_screen = Toplevel(screen)
    ga_screen.title('detail result')

    tree = ttk.Treeview(ga_screen)
    ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(tree, orient='vertical', command=tree.yview)
    xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(tree, orient='horizontal', command=tree.xview)
    tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set, xscroll=xsb.set)

    tree["columns"]=("two",'three','four')
    tree.column("#0", width=100)
    tree.column("two", width=100)
    tree.column('three', width=100)
    tree.column('four', width=100)
    tree.heading("#0", text="job number")
    tree.heading("two", text="process time",command=lambda: 
                     treeview_sort_column(tree,'two', False))
    tree.heading("three", text="finish time",command=lambda:
                     treeview_sort_column(tree,'three', False))
    tree.heading("four", text="due date",command=lambda: 
                     treeview_sort_column(tree,'four', False))

    for i in range(len(l_best)):
        prc_choosen = 0
        print('machine number:',i+1)
        for k in range(num_job):
            if k%mch_num_info ==i:
                prc_choosen=prc_choosen+p[sequence_best[k][0]][sequence_best[k][1]]
                print('job no', l[sequence_best[k][0]][sequence_best[k][1]],'prc time:',p[sequence_best[k][0]][sequence_best[k][1]]
                        ,'flow time:',prc_choosen,'due date:',d[sequence_best[k][0]][sequence_best[k][1]])

    for i in range(len(l_best)):
        prc_choosen = 0
        tree.insert("" , i,f'machine {i}', text=f"machine {i+1}")
        for k in range(num_job):
            if k%mch_num_info ==i:
                prc_choosen=prc_choosen+p[sequence_best[k][0]][sequence_best[k][1]]     
                tree.insert(f'machine {i}', i, text=f"job {l[sequence_best[k][0]][sequence_best[k][1]]}", 
                            values=(f"{p[sequence_best[k][0]][sequence_best[k][1]]}",
                                    f"{prc_choosen}",
                                    f'{d[sequence_best[k][0]][sequence_best[k][1]]}'))

    tree.pack()
```

Comment: I took another look at the question and am not able to answer it without more information. Try to avoid using so many global variables (like `l_best` and `num_job`) or if these are constants define them in all caps at the start of your program. Also, these are just function definitions. I don't know the order you execute your program. Please provide an executable but minimal version of your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more info.